# Point many domains to a single simple web form, using nothing but domain records configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, web-hosting, website, domains

**Context:** A friend of mine has a business selling domain names. As I work in IT as a C# developer he came to me with his request. Although I know little of these kind of things.

**Request:**
He wants to have his domains that are up for sale to point to 1 single web-form. Where people browsing the domain and who are interested can leave some sales-specific information. So he can reach out to these potential buyers.

**Requirement:**
It is essential that the potential buyer is not redirected from the domain they are browsing as shown in the URL of their browser and the domain is shown on the webform.

**Situation and scope:**
He can set DNS-settings of his domains by bulk. And this is all he wants to do: set the domain records and thats it.

**Additional less relevant situation:**
Now he and me both have websites and webhosting from a reseller party. So we have that available. But there does not seem to be a configuration option to have a 'catch-all domain' website, or a default website to point towards. So we have to think outside of that box.

**My hope:** I am sure there are legion of solutions to get this working... unfortunately I can't think of any from the top of my head. Can you please point me towards the most simple and easy way to get this working?

I allready found this post, but I am not sure if this applies to my situation:

[Configure the server & DNS like: Accept all domains that use our spesific nameservers](https://serverfault.com/questions/881149/configure-the-server-dns-like-accept-all-domains-that-use-our-spesific-namese)

I am a smart guy and not too lazy to find and read a manual, so I am sure in the long run I can figure it all out, but if you can save me a lot of time, by sharing your experience with me, I would be grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Now he and me both have websites and webhosting from a reseller party. So we have that available. But there does not seem to be a configuration option to have a 'catch-all domain' website, or a default website to point towards. So we have to think outside of that box.

Yes, the web hosting which doesn't permit you to have a "catch-all domain" is of no use here, both you and he have to "think outside that box".

Use another web hosting, with a dedicated IP, that will permit you to use "catch-all domain"; even cheapest VPS will do the thing. Or, add another domain name each time to the virtual server that hosts the form.  That's all, the only possible solutions.

(Implementing a "catch-all domain" web server is the "step one" in your linked relevant question. It is required. You need some means of serving all your domain names, so either you need to configure them all into the web server or have it serving the same thing regardless of what name was requested. This is how web server works.)

Comment: We don't want to go down the endless webserver configuration road. So we probably need a VPS. Now the follow up question is: where can we acquire a cheap VPS? ( Should it be with or without dedicated IP?)

Comment: It does not even have to be super cheap. As long as it works and is reliable.

Comment: This follow-up, a service recommendation, is off topic. STFW, there are tons of providers. Literally everywhere. Yes, you need an IP, and that IP is what you will be configuring in all your domains.

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf